# jQuery Mobile won't load page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a simple html doc with four jquery pages in it, each copied from the "home" page and modified.  Except for the actual id, all four have this structure:

```
<div data-role="page" id="facts"> 
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="nav"> 
  <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
  ...
  </div> 
 </div> 

 <div data-role="content" class="content_container">
  <div id="custom1">...</div>
  <div id="custom2">...</div>
 </div>
 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="nav">
  <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
   ...
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Three of the four pages load normally when their corresponding anchor button is pressed, but the fourth does not load at all, as if the page does not exist.  No error appears in the javascript console or elsewhere.  I have combed over the data-role divs and content, and all are correctly placed and well formed - closed just as the other three from which they were copied.  The id and hrefs are matched correctly.  Has anyone see this before?  I have not a lot of experience with Jquery Mobile, but have built a few sites with it and not had this problem before.  Thanks.

Comment: Is `facts` the id of the page that will not load? Do you have an anchor with `name="facts"` somewhere in your document?

Comment: Yes, "facts" is the page id.  Anchors to it are href="#facts", consistent with the others.  There is no anchor or any other element with name=facts.

Comment: Okay. No errors in your console and no other possible href target means we need more data. Can you catch `pagebeforeshow` and `pageshow` events (respectfully `pagecontainerbeforeshow` and `pagecontainershow`, depending on your jQM version) on that page / container?

Comment: you need to show all your code for your 4 pages

Comment: Tasos, the html is full of client information, and if I strip all of that out, there's not much left beyond what's represented above.  I realize it's not enough for evidence.  So I am just fishing for reasons why this could happen, assuming well-formed code.